# Query performance issue with query inside where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance

I have following somewhat complex `sql` query which has horrible performance, 'certainly' due to the inner query inside the `where` clause. In some cases it takes over a minute. Does anybody know how to rewrite this query giving better performance?

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id as taskId, t.name as taskName, 
  t.startdate as taskStartDate, t.enddate as taskEndDate, 
  t.proj_id as taskProjectId 
FROM PROJECT p, EMPL_PROJ ep, TASK t, TIMERECORD tr 
WHERE 
  ep.empl_id = ? AND 
  ep.proj_id = p.id AND 
  ep.proj_id = t.proj_id AND 
  ((p.startdate IS NULL AND p.enddate IS NULL) OR 
   (p.startdate IS NULL AND p.enddate >= ?) OR 
   (p.enddate IS NULL AND p.startdate <= ? + INTERVAL 6 DAY) OR 
   (p.startdate <= ? + INTERVAL 6 DAY AND p.enddate >= ?) ) AND 
  ((t.startdate IS NULL AND t.enddate IS NULL) OR 
   (t.startdate IS NULL AND t.enddate >= ?) OR 
   (t.enddate IS NULL AND t.startdate <= ? + INTERVAL 6 DAY) OR 
  (t.startdate <= ? + INTERVAL 6 DAY AND t.enddate >= ?)) AND 
  (
   (ep.empl_id = tr.empl_id AND 
    ep.proj_id = tr.proj_id AND 
    t.id = tr.task_id AND tr.day <= ? + INTERVAL 7 DAY AND 
    tr.day >= ? + INTERVAL -14 DAY
   ) OR 
   (
    (SELECT count(*) 
     FROM TIMERECORD tr2 
     WHERE 
     tr2.empl_id=ep.empl_id AND 
     tr2.proj_id=p.id AND tr2.day <= ? + INTERVAL 7 DAY AND 
     tr2.day >= ? + INTERVAL -14 DAY) <= 0
    )
  )
```

I'm using mysql server 5.1.40.

**Edit (2):**
With the comments and answers I came to this query which executes under a second (not bad coming from almost a minute!)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.id as taskId, t.name as taskName, 
  t.startdate as taskStartDate, t.enddate as taskEndDate, 
  t.proj_id as taskProjectId 
FROM (PROJECT p INNER JOIN EMPL_PROJ ep ON  ep.proj_id = p.id)  
  INNER JOIN TASK t ON p.id=t.proj_id 
  INNER JOIN TIMERECORD tr ON tr.empl_id=ep.empl_id AND tr.proj_id=ep.proj_id 
    AND tr.task_id=t.id
WHERE 
  ep.empl_id = ? AND 
  ((p.startdate IS NULL AND p.enddate IS NULL) OR 
   (p.startdate IS NULL AND p.enddate >= ?) OR 
   (p.enddate IS NULL AND p.startdate <= ? + INTERVAL 6 DAY) OR 
   (p.startdate <= ? + INTERVAL 6 DAY AND p.enddate >= ?) ) AND 
  ((t.startdate IS NULL AND t.enddate IS NULL) OR 
   (t.startdate IS NULL AND t.enddate >= ?) OR 
   (t.enddate IS NULL AND t.startdate <= ? + INTERVAL 6 DAY) OR 
   (t.startdate <= ? + INTERVAL 6 DAY AND t.enddate >= ?)) AND 
  (
   (
    tr.day <= ? + INTERVAL 7 DAY AND 
    tr.day >= ? + INTERVAL -14 DAY
   ) OR 
   (
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
      FROM TIMERECORD tr2 INNER JOIN EMPL_PROJ ON tr2.empl_id=EMPL_PROJ.empl_id 
        INNER JOIN PROJECT ON PROJECT.id=tr2.proj_id
      WHERE 
       tr2.day BETWEEN ? + INTERVAL -14 DAY AND ? + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
   )
  ) 
  ORDER BY p.id, t.id
```

Biggest contribution was the answer suggesting the `NOT EXISTS` approach (which I marked as being correct) and the comment not to mix the `explicit` and `implicit JOIN`'s.

Thanks to all!

Comment: "probably" can be upgraded to "certainty" by trying the query with, and without, the suspect part to see if its introduction causes the slowness. Doing this may also allow you to clear away irrelevant code in an effort to create a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), thus making your question more applicable to others and more easily answerable

Comment: @Bohemian :) I did this already, and for sure (certainly) the inner select statement is the cause of the performance issue. Just don't really know how to rewrite the query without it.

Comment: Step 1 would be using newer `JOIN` syntax instead of this old deprecated cross joins with where filters stuff.

Comment: @JNK I'm not that familiar with the newer `JOIN` syntax, if you would be so kind as to give me an example?

Comment: @jb10210 `INNER JOIN EMpl_Proj ep ON ep.proj_id = p.id` for example.  It makes the `JOIN` relationship much more obvious.

Comment: @JNK Did you mean something like: `... FROM PROJECT p INNER JOIN EMPL_PROJ ep ON  ep.proj_id = p.id, TASK t INNER JOIN EMPL_PROJ ON EMPL_PROJ.proj_id=t.proj_id, ...`? Because this query takes my sql server into timeout (+1min)

Comment: With the comma in your join statment you probaly made a cross join between empll_proj and task. That is why it si taking so long.YOu never ever want to mix implicit and explicit joins or the results are often unfortunate. But you should not be writing implict joins ever, they were replaced 20 years ago and there is no excuse for using them in  2012.

Comment: @HLGEM I updated my question with my new query, but the `INNER JOIN`s don't have an impact on performance, only the `NOT EXISTS` statement

Comment: Your "?" values -- with respect to the dates.  I am under the assumption they are the same value for all dates... ex: a specific date or current_date()... OR... are they different dates for the project vs task dates.

Comment: @DRapp they are indeed the same for all dates

Comment: Another question. your qualifications on dates have EndDates that are >= ?, but your start dates are <= ? + interval 6 days.  Did you intend the start date to be 6 days BEFORE the date in question?  I've never known a system that had the end date before the start date

Comment: @DRapp The query returns a week view, so the start date may be within the next 7days (the date '?' is always the first day of a week). At creation of projects and tasks it is made sure the start and end dates are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using COUNT(*) when you seem to only need a NOT EXISTS...

```
(
(SELECT count(*) 
 FROM TIMERECORD tr2 
 WHERE 
 tr2.empl_id=ep.empl_id AND 
 tr2.proj_id=p.id AND tr2.day <= ? + INTERVAL 7 DAY AND 
 tr2.day >= ? + INTERVAL -14 DAY) <= 0
)
```

Replace with

```
(
NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
 FROM TIMERECORD tr2 
 WHERE 
 tr2.empl_id=ep.empl_id AND 
 tr2.proj_id=p.id AND tr2.day <= ? + INTERVAL 7 DAY AND 
 tr2.day >= ? + INTERVAL -14 DAY)
)
```

Now if a TIMERECORD does exist that part of the where clause will short circuit to FALSE (NOT TRUE) without having to count every TIMERECORD.

Comment: +1 Great remark! It already significantly reduces the query response time (from +10s to about 5-6s). But the same query without the select in the where clause (which sends more data) runs in about 1s. So this should be reduced somewhat more.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the sub query.

(1). Compute the sub query separately with the columns empl_id,proj_id,count(*) for all empl_ids & proj_ids where the day  falls in the required range. This is a simple group by query.

```
select empl_id,proj_id,count(*) as ct from TIMERECORD 
where day between (? + INTERVAL -14 DAY) and (? + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
group by empl_id,proj_id;
```

Call this result set B

(2). Compute the remaining query as you are doing now. Call this resultset A

(3). Do A left outer join B using columns empl_id,proj_id that are common in A & B

then in the where clause you can check the value in B.ct column, it will be null for all empl_id,proj_id combinations for which no entry was found in TIMERECORD table for the given time range.

Actually you don't even need count(*) since you are not bothered about the actual count. But let me not complicate it more than necessary.

Comment: -1 - you've been around 11 months and should understand how code tagging works by now.

Comment: @Priyank thanks for the `between` keyword, didn't know it existed! +1

Comment: @JNK Who are you? I don't care if something like that offends you so much. More so if ur going to be rude about it. I have my explanation about why I didn't do it but I don't owe you one.

Comment: @Priyank - I'm just another user.  I wasn't being rude, but not editing code is extremely lazy and shows you don't really care about the people who have to read your post.  I didn't imply you owed me an explanation, and TBH I didn't have to explain the downvote but I did.

Comment: @JNK I wouldn't have replied if I didn't care. Secondly I don't use stackoverflow that much to know all its features. 11 months says nothing about how much I use it.

Comment: @Priyank OK, well in the future please highlight your code with code tags.  The easiest way is to select the code then his `CTRL+K`.